# extract an element from an html declaration

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I am using scrapy selectors and I am trying to extract the element "1" in from the HTML declaration below:

```
<li aria-label="Pagina" class="page active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
```

I have two equal declarations in the whole HTML source content.

---

```
<div class="row paging-bar">
    <ul class="sync-pagination pagination pull-right">
       <li aria-label="Pagina" class="prev"><a href="#">&lt;</a></li>
       <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
       <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">2</a></li>
       <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">3</a></li>
       <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">4</a></li>
       <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">5</a></li>
       <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">6</a></li>
       <li><span>...</span></li>
       <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">1405</a></li>
      <li aria-label="Pagina" class="next"><a href="#">&gt;</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
<div class="row paging-bar">
    <ul class="sync-pagination pagination pull-right">
       <li aria-label="Pagina" class="prev"><a href="#">&lt;</a></li>
       <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
       <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">2</a></li>
       <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">3</a></li>
       <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">4</a></li>
       <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">5</a></li>
       <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">6</a></li>
       <li><span>...</span></li>
       <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">1405</a></li>
       <li aria-label="Pagina" class="next"><a href="#">&gt;</a></li>
    </ul>
</div></div>
```

---

I have tried the command:

```
response.xpath("normalize-space(//li[@class='page active']/a[@href]/text())").extract_first()
```

but it returned an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It works.

```py
>>> html = """
... <div class="row paging-bar">
...     <ul class="sync-pagination pagination pull-right">
...        <li aria-label="Pagina" class="prev"><a href="#">&lt;</a></li>
...        <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
...        <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">2</a></li>
...        <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">3</a></li>
...        <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">4</a></li>
...        <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">5</a></li>
...        <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">6</a></li>
...        <li><span>...</span></li>
...        <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">1405</a></li>
...       <li aria-label="Pagina" class="next"><a href="#">&gt;</a></li>
...     </ul>
... </div>
... """
>>> from parsel import Selector
>>> selector = Selector(text=html)
>>> selector.xpath("normalize-space(//li[@class='page active']/a[@href]/text())").extract_first()
'1'
>>> html = """
... <div class="row paging-bar">
...     <ul class="sync-pagination pagination pull-right">
...        <li aria-label="Pagina" class="prev"><a href="#">&lt;</a></li>
...        <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
...        <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">2</a></li>
...        <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">3</a></li>
...        <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">4</a></li>
...        <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">5</a></li>
...        <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">6</a></li>
...        <li><span>...</span></li>
...        <li aria-label="Pagina" class="page"><a href="#">1405</a></li>
...        <li aria-label="Pagina" class="next"><a href="#">&gt;</a></li>
...     </ul>
... </div></div>
... """
>>> selector = Selector(text=html)
>>> selector.xpath("normalize-space(//li[@class='page active']/a[@href]/text())").extract_first()
'1'
```

Comment: Thank you Gallaecio. I was testing your solution which is what I need, and found that I was running scrapy on a python2.7 ENV, when it sent an error with the command "selector = Selector(text=html)". I am going to reinstall ENV for python3... hopefully.

Comment: Hello Gallaecio. I have tested your solution and it works exactly as you show in your answer. But in my program I always get an empty string.

Comment: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy from parsel import Selector
class ArtigosJumboSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "artigos_jumbo"
    start_urls = ['https://www.jumbo.pt/Frontoffice/search/%C2%A8#?pn=1',]
    def parse(self, response): ... selector = Selector(text=THEPROBLEMISHERE)                    page_active=selector.xpath("normalize-space(//li[@class='page active']/a[@href]/text())").extract_first()

Comment: Please, update your question providing code that allows to reproduce your issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example